# custom validator in angular4 material table results error

Tags: angular, angular-material-table, angular-custom-validators, mat-form-field

I am using angular4-material-table . there I tried to add custom input validation
I have created seperate validator service there I called custom function to hit my api based on api result it will throws input valid or not.

here is my code can anyone suggest me what mistake I made,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ValidatorService } from 'angular4-material-table';
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ApiCallService } from 'api.service';

    @Injectable()
    export class MatTableValidatorService implements ValidatorService {
        constructor( private api_call: ApiCallService) {  
        }
       getRowValidator(): FormGroup {
        return new FormGroup({
          'name': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, this.nameValidator]),
          });
      }
        nameValidator(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null {
            this.api_call
            .api_function(parameter)
            .subscribe(data => {
              const arrayVal = data.response;
              if(arrayVal.length > 0)
              {
                return {'dnsCheck': true}
              }
              return null;
          });
            return null;
        }

    }
```

this one returns error : cannot read property of api_call even though I declared it in constructor

and another way:

```
   public nameValidator = (control: AbstractControl) => {
         this.api_call
            .api_function(parameter)
            .subscribe(data => {
              const arrayVal = data.response;
              if(arrayVal.length > 0)
              {
                return {'dnsCheck': true}
              }
              return null;
          });
        };
```

this way works but even though input valid or not it always throws error. I have checked output with console seems getting from api is perfectly done. can anyone assist me whats my mistake.
Thanks in advance.

[A stackblitz example can be seen here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n9jfvb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether it is a reason, however you are not awaiting result of your api call. Your code always return `null`. So we need to await result of API call:

```
async nameValidator(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null {  
    const result = await this.api_call.api_function(parameter);
    const arrayVal = result.response;

    if (arrayVal.length > 0)
          return {'dnsCheck': true}

    return null;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

You can add custom validator. Forbidden name is `Mark`, if you write forbidden name, then input will not save this value:

```
@Injectable()
export class PersonValidatorService implements ValidatorService {
  getRowValidator(): FormGroup {
    return new FormGroup({
      'name': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, forbiddenNameValidator()])

      });
  }
}

export function forbiddenNameValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {    
    const forbidden =  'Mark';
    console.log(`forbidden name is `, forbidden);
    return (forbidden == control.value) ? {'forbiddenName': {value: control.value}} : null;
  };
}
```

[An example can be seen here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ftstt8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fperson-validator.service.ts)

Comment: Thanks for sharing . I tried with async await one thing api function is not returning value do we need to subscribe or pipe,map to get data

Comment: and as values not returns core.js:12584 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at MatTableValidatorService.<anonymous> (m

Comment: I just added toPromise now its working still formcontrol returns error for right input

Comment: I gave console inside arrayval>0 it returns true but still formcontrol in error span

Comment: @KavyaShree could you create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) example?

Comment: Sure I will @stepup

Comment: @KavyaShree I do not have enogh time to find error, however, I've found a work example like your. Please, see my updated answer. Thanks.

Comment: yeah I checked the example can u add sample custom validation with this, because validator required working fine custom validation is my problem

Answer (score 0):

Angular Custom Validations contains a different scope and therefor the first example you made did not work.

The second example did work since you used 'arrow function'.
Because your custom validation is async, you need to return an observable.
Take a look at the following

First option:

```
nameValidator = (control: AbstractControl): Observable<{ [key: string]: boolean } | null> => {
    return this.api_call
        .api_function(parameter)
        .pipe(
            map(
                data => {
                    const arrayVal = data.response;
                    return arrayVal && arrayVal.length > 0 ? { 'dnsCheck': true } : null
                }
            )
        );
}
```

Second Options:

this.nameValidator.bind(this) is where the magic happens

```
getRowValidator(): FormGroup {
    return new FormGroup({
        'name': new FormControl(null, {
            asyncValidators: [this.nameValidator.bind(this)],
            validators: [Validators.required],
        }),
    });
}

nameValidator(control: AbstractControl): Observable < { [key: string]: boolean } | null > {
    return this.api_call
        .api_function(parameter)
        .pipe(
            map(
                data => {
                    const arrayVal = data.response;
                    return arrayVal && arrayVal.length > 0 ? { 'dnsCheck': true } : null
                }
            )
        );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me . still im getting this error DnsDashboardComponent.html:29 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'api_call' of undefined
    at push../src/app/@core/matTable-validator.service.ts.MatTableValidatorService.nameValidator

Comment: when you declare the field add the "bind" function, like this: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, this.nameValidator.bind(this)]). this way you explicitly say that the custom validation function has the same scope as the component. I will edit the comment.

Comment: I updated the code now error gone, but api is not returns value inside map i tried to console api hits but no response

Comment: can you check ?

Comment: I updated the comment. take a look at the asyncValidators

Comment: I tried with async as well @ben still I couldn't resolved this issue

Comment: async dnsValidator(control: AbstractControl) 
{
    const result = await this.api_call
    .api_function(parameter).toPromise();
    const arrayVal = result.response;
    if (arrayVal.length > 0)
      {   console.log("true result"); return {'dnsCheck': true} }
    return null;
} and in console i can see this "true" aswell